# How to create route using osm.pbf by road between coordinates in R or Python?

Tags: python, r, shiny, rstudio, openstreetmap

I have *.osm.pbf file but I don't know if it's possible to work with it in R or Python for creating route visualization between two lat-lon points. As an answer, I need to get a map image with a route between them. If the map can be interactive and moveable, that would be great, but a static image will do.

It's important that it's offline. Although yes, it would be easier to use data from google or online osm, but I can't do that.